# Django Rest- filtering results to show first variation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to filter my results to only show the **first** "Variation" class pointing **to** "Product" class.

I almost want it to work like this:

```
'product__variation__image__image'[0],
```

OR

```
'product_set__variation__image__image'[0],
```

I tried using:

```
 .distinct('product_pk')
```

But this would not work if I was using .order_by()

The below code works, but each item is repeated several times as it has variations relating to it.

Here's a snippet of my Django rest views:

```
wardrobematch = {
    'user': lambda x: ('user__pk', x)  
}

class WardrobeListView(APIView):

    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        filters = {}
        for key, value in request.GET.items():
            key = key.lower()
            if key in wardrobematch:
                lookup, val = wardrobematch[key](value.lower())
                filters[lookup] = val

    qset = (
        Analytic.objects
        .filter(like=True,**filters)
        # .distinct('product_id',)
        .values('product_id', 'product__name', 'product__brand', 'product__store__store_name', 'product__variation__image__image', 'product__variation__price__price', 'updated',)

    )

    result = sorted(qset, key=lambda obj: obj.updated)
    return Response(serializers.serialize("json", result))
```

Comment: Are you using sqlite by any chance? It does not support `DISTINCT`. To make the `DISTINCT` statement work, switch to MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: On PostgreSQL. Just updated question- can get it working using .distinct but this breaks "order_by". I need to use both. Here is the traceback http://dpaste.com/1G7F8YC

Comment: Your traceback says that your `distinct()` should match your `order_by()`. Have you tried putting your `product_pk` into your `order_by()`?

Comment: Yes but that sorts it by product_pk. I want it sorted by the field 'updated' in the analytics class (as in example above)

Comment: Did my proposed solution solve your problem? Or do you still struggle with any problem?

Comment: No- still not working. Can you update your answer to include the part about httpresponse? Not sure how view is relvent- it's just a json output...

Comment: You could serialize the result and return it as Response object.

Comment: Still says "'dict' object has no attribute 'created'". traceback here: http://dpaste.com/0CPADAZ

Comment: Mate, your code does not match your stacktrace. You need to use updated and not created.

Comment: Ignore that, I changed it for a test. Definitely is "updated" (as per this trace http://dpaste.com/3PN4Q4P)

Comment: You need to access the obj as dict. Change .updated to ['updated']

Comment: So now it tells me dict has no attribute _meta. http://dpaste.com/1R5HB1N

Comment: Seems you need to use json package. Take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Needed an extra bracket, but now telling me json is not definable (http://dpaste.com/0X7BZWD).

Comment: Import it... It's a standard python module.

Comment: That gives me a typeerror (decimal 100.00 is not json serilizable). http://dpaste.com/24WV0ZA

Comment: Just restructure your result into a dict that is serializable.

Answer (score 0):

> When you specify field names, you must provide an order_by() in the QuerySet, and the fields in order_by() must start with the fields in distinct(), in the same order.

Taken from: [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct).

You could sort it afterwards anyway.

```
qs = Analytic.objects.filter(like=True,**filters)
        .distinct('product_pk',) 
        .values('product_pk', 'product__name', 'product__brand', 'product__store__store_name', 'product__variation__image__image', 'product__variation__price__price', 'updated')
result = sorted(qs, key=lambda obj: obj['updated'])
return Response(json.dumps({'result': result}))
```

Comment: Thanks. Your example says 'dict' object has no attribute 'updated'. 'Updated' is within the analytics class so unsure why i can't find it. I have updated my above code to show what I've attempted.

Comment: You did not update the values. Take a look at the values, the last one in my example is `updated`.

Comment: That gives me an assertion error (Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<type 'NoneType'>`). I've updated my question with my existing code above

Comment: Yes, because views need to return an `HttpResponse` and not any arbitrary Python object or nothing. You need to return.